# error TS2314: Generic type 'Type<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). Why do I get this error?

Tags: angularjs, angular

While upgrading to Angular RC5 , I get errors in node modules which are like:

error TS2314: Generic type 'Type' requires 1 type argument(s).

in  in /@angular/common/src/common_directives.d.ts(54,41)